# Why is the document.onreadystatechange function executed in advance?

Tags: web-console

```js
console.time('onload')
console.time('onreadystatechange')
window.onload = ()=>{console.log('onload'); console.timeEnd('onload')}
document.onreadystatechange = ()=>{console.log('onreadystatechange');console.log(document.readyState);console.timeEnd('onreadystatechange')}
```

I wrote the above code in an inline script, why the result is the following?

In theory, `console.time('onreadystatechange')` should be executed first, but from the results, the `onreadystatechange` event is executed first, and `document.readyState` is 'complete', why is the event advanced?

Answer (score 1):

There will be other state changes before `document.readyState` becomes complete.

At that time, the `onreadystatechange` function will be triggered.

`console.timeEnd('onreadystatechange')` is used in `onreadystatechange`.

When `console.timeEnd` is called, the timer corresponding to this record is cleared.

So when the subsequent `onreadystatechange` function is called again, there will be a prompt because there is no restart to set the `onreadystatechange` timer.

The entire execution sequence is consistent with the standard definition, and there is no problem.